# Victim of serial downvoting, undownvoted, but still banned. How to lift the ban?

Tags: support, post-ban, serial-voting

I'm aware there are already similar threads like this one but none of those answered my question. I recently was the victim of some serial downvoting, because of this I wasn't allowed to ask any questions anymore, luckily the system reverted those downvotes but after the reversion I noticed I still couldn't ask any questions.

Here's what I've already tried:

- Answer questions (which I always do on a regular basis)
- Tried to find a way to improve my questions, but couldn't seem to find any way.

What can I do to get rid of the annoying question ban? I have a question. `:)`

Comment: Wow, you have quite a lot of rep for a question ban... keep up the good answering.

Comment: On what site are you banned? I see no sign of serial downvoting, reversal of serial downvoting, or a question ban (unless you've got a bunch of deleted questions).

Comment: I'm banned on Stackoverflow, I have one deleted questions which was deleted by "Community" (the bot). My profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2019515/user2019515

Comment: How could you be question banned with only three questions (visible in your profile)?  Something else seems unusual here.

Comment: Well, if that's the case I'd like to know what that is so I can fix it. :)

Comment: I don't understand why you were banned?

Comment: I don't understand either, and the thread this is a "duplicate" of gave me no answers. So... if anyone got some spare votes.... ;)

Comment: Votes won't help you - your raw vote counts wouldn't trigger a question ban, so upvotes wouldn't remove it. You'll need to wait for a diamond mod to step in and evaluate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not banned due to serial downvoting. You're banned due to three downvoted and deleted questions.

- [What is the correct MySQL date format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16616660/1288)
- [WordPress dashboard change menu item text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15298588/1288)
- [301 correct way to redirect a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14753024/1288) (Another moderator already undeleted it for you though, so it's a good place to start with improvements.)

You need to follow the same procedure as anyone else that's question banned.

Comment: I see, how come the ban only kicked in just a few days ago, even though those questions have been removed for quite a while. Also, how can I improve the questions if they have been closed, I don't believe I can?

Comment: The question that likely got you banned was only 4 days ago. I don't know when the question ban started though. You can still edit deleted questions and ask for them to be undeleted if you think they're salvageable, but usually they're not.  You need to improve your other questions and keep answering other people's questions to lift the ban.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll do just that.

Comment: If it isn't too much trouble, could you find out how/why that question was deleted by the community user? I don't see how it could be considered rude or spam so it's odd that it can get deleted like that.

Comment: @JeffMercado George Stocker figured out that it was because the question was at -1 with no activity for 3 months. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181259/1288

Comment: I flagged the `301 correct way to redirect a directory` because I wanted to answer it. Currently unbanned, happy me. :)