# Can the system leave a deletion reason when it deletes a question?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, auto-delete

[A user asked why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181257/victim-of-serial-downvoting-undownvoted-but-still-banned-how-to-lift-the-ban) they were question banned; it turned out it (in part) it was because of deleted questions.

[One of the deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753024/301-correct-way-to-redirect-a-directory#question) was deleted by the Community user.  I'm aware it will delete old posts that have a negative score, but for a minute or two, I was really puzzled as to why it was unilaterally deleted without some notation left.

Can we have the Community user leave a notation in a post's history as to *why* the post was deleted?

Something like the following would suffice:

> Post deleted automatically due to having negative votes and no activity for three months

Comment: +1 - I was scratching my head over this one as well.

Comment: I'm sure there's a post somewhere on meta that explains this behavior, but I'll be damned if I can remember where. Also: Once a system becomes sufficiently complex, it is indistinguishable from Skynet.

Comment: Another thing we should talk about is whether these posts should count towards the ban. It's pretty easy to come by one downvote.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - Shog detailed how things are going to be handled here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/135615, but I think that's waiting on the rewrites to the flag system they're working on. I believe Jeff's answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/135615 describes the current process.

Comment: @Seth That's going to be a difficult question to address; the devs won't be able to acknowledge it, or acknowledge that it's fixed. All we can do is say "it would be stupid if they were weighted equally," then hope they see it.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi That's true.. I forgot we don't even know if they *are* weighted equally in the first place.

Comment: Related: [Add a reject reason when the Community user rejects an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153403/152859)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The deletion notice on a question now includes the scheduled process which caused the Community user to delete the question:

[image: Deletion Notice]

One of:

- RemoveMigrationStubs
- RemoveDeadQuestions
- RemoveAbandonedQuestions
- RemoveAbandonedClosed

You can see what each of these terms means in [this answer which outlines the criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006).

Comment: Seems that it is "Removed" (with a 'd') instead of "Remove". Can you confirm?