# RemovedAbandonedClosed

Tags: support, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, community-user, auto-delete

Appears that *RemovedAbandonedClosed* is added after the date of the question removal, if the question is deleted by Community.

[image]

Though it acts as a reason of removal (:P), I doubt it's intentional?

Comment: It is the result from the Roomba script but it doesn't come with a friendly message, just the enum value as text...

Comment: Another case: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267030/245360.

Comment: [Andy's answer below](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268935/removedabandonedclosed/268943#268943) is the correct one here. This was recently implemented, and is intentional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is intentional.

Animuson explains what reasons are available in a post for this [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267439/186281):

> - RemoveMigrationStubs
> - RemoveDeadQuestions
> - RemoveAbandonedQuestions
> - RemoveAbandonedClosed

An explanation of how each status is defined is explained further in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/186281)

Answer (score 0):

Intentional or not, I find this very useful. Deleted questions aren't visible to regular users, so putting useful information about the deletion directly visible to viewers is a good point.

The text might be formatted a little better, maybe linked to some FAQ about the Roomba script, but besides that: please leave it there!

Comment: I agree it doesn't harm anyone to display this info. But apart from being sort of an example to the linked help article, it doesn't seem to be really useful...  You can, of course, sort those roomba-removed questions by the exact reason of removal, however it won't give you anything, will it? This info also won't affect your decision whether vote to undelete the question or not.

Comment: True but it helps to diagnose why your (or someone else's) question was deleted. We get those questions often right?

Comment: And now you have a notice with the link to the help article :) Moreover, I don't get "RemoveDeadQuestions" in "another case" you linked (but when I click the link, everything gets clear once I read the first point - the need of these stats again?) - the  confusions like mine can lead to the new questions. If the info remains there, it's worth probably to make a list explaining each stat.

Comment: That would be a feature request I would support :)