# Typo in roomba deletion reason: RemovedAbandonedClosed has an extra "d"

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, spelling

When a closed question gets automatically deleted, the reason of deletion which is displayed is "Remove**d**AbandonedClosed", but the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) says it should be "RemoveAbandonedClosed" (without the extra "d").

[image]

Comment: Also here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006 | And by the way: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181259/can-the-system-leave-a-deletion-reason-when-it-deletes-a-question/267439#comment880619_267439

Comment: Maybe that would be easier to get rid of Roomba.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Sounds plausible... Removing 1 character is pretty hard. :)

Comment: @AdamLear can you check related question in [meta.ruSO](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3868/176217)?

Comment: @alexolut That is unfortunately not a trivial fix. :/ I think it's possible to add a translation. I'll ask around and see what we can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derp derp. Thanks for noticing/reporting. I'm not gonna do a prod build for a minor typo, but posts deleted as of some time on Monday will have the correct Roomba reason listed.

The fix isn't retroactive. I'll see what the impact is on Monday and fix up previously recorded reasons if it's not too complicated to do.